# Woken or Have woken

Tags: past-participles, perfect-aspect, conversational-deletion

*Woken* up late . I had to take a taxi to attend the first lecture.

OR

*Have woken* up late . I had to take a taxi to attend the first lecture.

Which one is the correct sentence, please help me guys as soon as possible.

Comment: Could you include the rest of the first sentence?

Comment: Correct are 'Having woken up late, I had to take a taxi to make it to the first lecture.' _and_  'Waking up late, I had to take a taxi to make it to the first lecture.' This is the intransitive usage of wake [up], = _cease being asleep_. Contrast 'Having woken Bill up, I phoned for a taxi to take me to the lecture.' The transitive usage, equivalent to  _perform the intended function of an alarm clock_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Actually, "Woken up late" would be valid if your mother were late waking you up.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are trying to say. I assume you mean

*I woke up late [this morning] and had to take a taxi to attend the first lecture.*

*Woken up late* suggests *I was woken up late* (that is, someone else woke you up).

Comment: Not an ELU question.

Comment: Can we use "Woken up late." as a sentence except in spoken English? If written, it sounds non-finite with no time attached to it.

Comment: @RamPillai See this recent discussion on what constitutes a sentence! https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/561516/is-canned-meats-rated-a-valid-and-correct-english-sentence

Comment: @KateBunting, yes I had seen that.

Answer (score 0):

Woken up late would be a wrong phrase when referring to yourself, doing the action of waking up yourself. It would probably mean that somebody else was doing the task of waking you up, so woken up late would be the passive form of 'She/he woke me up late', which is I was 'woken' up late(i.e.somebody else was doing this). Had woken would also not be the best choice since your second statement is in the simple past tense, so it wouldn't be quite right to have your first one in past perfect tense. Hence the best way to say this according to me would be: Woke up late. I had to take a taxi to attend the first lecture.